# How to skip active window from Desktop sharing

Tags: java, winapi

I'm working on virtual class room project and using Red5 screen share application for sharing my desktop with users.
It is sharing my entire desktop, but I don't want to share a particular application window, in which I do some personal work.

```
User32Extra.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hWnd,0); // for hiding window 
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height)); User32Extra.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hWnd,5); // for showing window
```

I'm using winapi for hiding particular window, but its not giving proper result.

Comment: `User32Extra.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hWnd,0)`; // for hiding window  
`BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height))`;  
`User32Extra.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hWnd,5)`; // for showing window

Comment: In the above scenario, I'm successfully skipping window from sharing, but the window is fluctuating with hide and show, by that I'm unable to use it. window should remain active and interactive with user without any fluctuations.

Comment: You could call [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340.aspx), passing a `WDA_MONITOR` parameter. Depending on the internals of Red5 this will prevent the respective window's visual representation from being accessible to the application.

Comment: `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` is not giving any results to me, Here i'm using this function in the below format.    `User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hWnd, 0);`// hWnd is HWND of my personal window.     `HWND desktop =User32.INSTANCE.GetDesktopWindow();
      BufferedImage image =target.capture(desktop);`  //desktop is the HWND of User32.INSTANCE.GetDesktopWindow().     `User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hWnd,0);`  I didn't find positive results for me. Is this the correct way to use this function? Plz suggest me the way

Comment: 'SetWindowDisplayAffinity()' is working only if I disable **Desktop Window Manager**. But, after disabling this, my system theme is automatically changing to **Windows 7 basic**, which I don't want.    How can I make it work without changing the theme of the system?